# A good way to construct a vector of 2d array

Tags: c++

What I want to do is

```
double A[2][2] = { 
                      {4, 7},
                      {2, 6}
                 };
std::vector<double[2][2]> B; 
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
  B.push_back(A);
}
```

But C++ cannot store an array in std::vector, what is the proper (speed) way to do that? Is `A[2][2]` faster than `std::array`due to cache coherency?

Comment: Use `std::array` instead of C style arrays?

Comment: you can use `std::vector<double**>` if you want but I also recommend `std::array`

Comment: C style arrays are second class citizens, inheriting unfortunate properties from C. In a lot of cases they don't behave like other objects. Containers usually aren't adapted to allow them as element type.

Comment: Please don't add more questions to an existing question via edits. However `std::array` is essentially a thin wrapper around C style arrays, their performance should be identical (if you run into a case where you can measure a difference that would warrant a new question)

Comment: What do you think "cache coherency" is, and what leads you to believe that it has anything to do with the difference between C-style arrays and `std::array`?

Answer (score 3):

`std::array` is probably the best way to go here. It should preform nearly identically to the C style array you've got:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    using Array2d = std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 2>;

    Array2d A = {{{4, 7}, {2, 6}}};
    std::vector<Array2d> B; 
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        B.push_back(A);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do I have C++ incomplete type is not allowed and Local variable is not initialized for ```Array2d A```? I am using visual studio 2019, but I am not sure is this related to C++ version?

Comment: @user590270 Sounds like you didn't `#include <array>`.

Comment: ```using Array2d = std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 4>;     Array2d B;     std::fill(std::begin(B), std::end(B), 1);``` I try to initialize the 2d array with 1, but it has error C2679, binary '=' no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const_Ty', so how to initialize 2d array instead of using for loop?

Comment: That's probably a good question for another post, but you'd want to do something like `for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i) for (size_t j = 0; j < 2; ++j) B[i][j] = 1;`